# In need of a high performance C# collection that do not enforce data consistency

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I'm in a massively parallel context with a large (a lot of large objects) static collection.

I cannot find any implementation of a collection that do not enforce data consistency. They all try to enforce it using internal locking, versioning (eg : List), or local copying (eg : ConcurrentBag).

- `List<T>` works very well, but use versionning and Throw a `InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion`
- `ConcurrentBag<T>` shown a drop in performance in my code. It's GC intensive and assume a producer/consumer pattern. It iterate over a "snapshot" (ThreadLocal) of the bag for data consistency purpose but i'm memory constrained.
- i checked the `Net Framework` and `Net Core` source code of the two aforementioned collection.

**I need a collection with the following features :**

- do not lock at any time implicitly. i'll do the locking myself.
- do not throw any exception because the data i'm reading may be inconsistent (non-atomic operation), i know, and it's ok.
- do not copy itself
- need to be mutable
- need to be able to add/remove an element (which may require an explicit lock, i'm ok with a lock for this rare case)
- Size is unknown at compile time and maximum size is "until the system run out of memory and the program crash". (no array)
- Useable with foreach and Parallel.ForEach
- do not need to be ordered
- can be read by multiple thread, can be written by multiple thread, all at the same time. regardless of any possible data consistency problem. (it must not use "version" internally)

`LinkedList<T>` was promising but it seems to have the same "version" consistency-protection as List, from the source code ( https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/LinkedList.cs#L564 ):

```
if (_version != _list.version)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
}
```

Do i need to create my own implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1), and enumerate it with a `for` loop, handling any `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exceptions that may occur:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsInconsistentEnumerable<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        T current;
        try
        {
            current = list[i];
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
foreach (var item in myList.AsInconsistentEnumerable())
{
    //...
}
```

Regarding the size of this collection, you can go up to 2 billion elements ([`Int32.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue)) in 64-bit platforms, by configuring the [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element) option in your App.config.

Comment: Sound like a good idea since `for` doesn't enumerate (afaik) it won't trigger the versioning check... probably :)